# How does the question seeding work?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, posts

When I first found this network (from Math SE), I was questioning why the question seed was combined along with the answers.

If I were to look at the revisions, the link would show `posts` instead of `questions`.

For example, [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/how-to-convert-decimal-to-double-in-c-sharp/7#7)'s link is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/how-to-convert-decimal-to-double-in-c-sharp/7#7`, and setting to revisions would be `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7/revisions`.

Why is this the way Stack Exchange seeds their posts?

Comment: There only exists one concept: Posts. Those work for both questions and answers, so does `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7` or `https://stackoverflow.com/q/7` or `https://stackoverflow.com/a/7`. The posts route is just for handling generic actions on any post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As rene said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359287/how-does-the-question-seeding-work/359300#comment1199329_359287), both questions and answers are posts. They are stored in the same table, so the ids are effectively coming from the same pool of numbers. In your example, the question is a post with id 4 and the answer is a post with id 7.